# how can i create this layout using flex container css properties

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <style> body{margin: 0px;} body> div { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; } body>div>nav,header,main,main,main { border-radius: 3px;margin: 5px;padding: 10px; } body>div>nav {order:2;height:100px;flex:0 1 80%;} body>div>header{order:1;flex: 200px;} body>div>main{order:3;align:right;min-height:400px;flex:1;} body>div>main{order:4;flex: 0 1 200px;} </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
      <nav>ex it</nav>
      <header>flexem</header>
      <main>hshsad</main>
      <main>hsgdhsgd </main>
      </header> 
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Please help, I'm new to HTML and CSS

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: please provide the code inside question itself by editing the question , not as a comment.

Comment: I have done this but still not working will please anyone provide whole code i'm trying this from 6 days need real help btw i'm newbie and now i'm trying with the display: table property

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example.
Flexbox properties aren't as magical as they look, it may be better to set a flexbox container *inside* your first one.

```css
/* Your 1st level container */
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* Just setting borders */
#container aside, #container main section, #container main div {
  border: 5px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

aside {
  width: 25%;
  height: 600px;
}

/* This is the 2nd flexbox container */
main {
  width: 75%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

main section {
  width: 95%;
  height: 275px;
}

#container main div {
  width: 30%;
  height: 275px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <aside></aside>
  <main>
    <section></section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah it works fine but do i create this with the help of "display table" property ?

Comment: @ArchanGhatpande I am not sure of what you mean. I used the `display: flex` and other flexbox properties (`flex-flow`, `justify-content`). `display: table` will make your block act like a `<table>`. See [MDN - display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) and [MDN - Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)